# can the Fragment be backed to previous fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to back the default fragment from the other fragment when the back button is clicked but i am not able to back to the previous fragment.How can this be achieved??

**EduHunt class** main class

```
   public class EduHunt extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    TextView toolBarTitle;
    ImageView toolBarLogo;


    private Fragment mTabHost;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edu_hunt);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolBarLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toolbarlogo);
        toolBarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbartitle);


        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tx.replace(R.id.flContent, new Search());

        tx.commit();


    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                fragmentClass = Search.class;
                toolBarLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toolBarTitle.setText("Search");
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                fragmentClass = Settings.class;
                toolBarLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toolBarTitle.setText("About");
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                fragmentClass = Register.class;
                toolBarLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toolBarTitle.setText("Register Now");
                break;
            case R.id.nearme:
                fragmentClass = NearMe.class;
                toolBarLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toolBarTitle.setText("Near Me");
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = Search.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.our_team:
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_our_team);
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            case R.id.feedback:
                startActivity(new Intent(EduHunt.this, SendFeedback.class));
                return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.education_hunt, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.flContent);

        if(!(fragment instanceof Search )){

            FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.flContent, new Search());

            tx.commit();
        }
    }


}
```

I want to back to the Search fragment(default fragment) when it is backed from the Any other fragment i.e About

**About**

```
public class About extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    LinearLayout collegeAffiliation;
    ImageView phoneCalls, sendEmails, weblink;

    public TextView aboutName, aboutLocation, aboutNumber, aboutEmail, aboutWebsite, aboutCategory, aboutAffiliation;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
        collegeAffiliation = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.collegeAffiliation);

        aboutName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_school_name);
        aboutLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_school_location);
        aboutNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_school_number);
        aboutCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_school_category);
        aboutAffiliation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_college_affiliation);
        aboutEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_school_email);
        aboutWebsite = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_school_website);
        phoneCalls = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.phonecalls);
        sendEmails = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.sendEmails);
        weblink = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.weblink);
        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;


                OurSchool ourSchool = null;
                OurCollege ourCollege = null;
                OurUniversity ourUniversity = null;
                if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school") != null) {
                    ourSchool = (OurSchool) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school");
                    aboutName.setText(ourSchool.getSchoolName());
                    aboutLocation.setText(ourSchool.getSchoolAddress() + "," + ourSchool.getSchoolDistrict() + "," + ourSchool.getSchoolCountry());
                    aboutNumber.setText(ourSchool.getSchoolPhone());
                    aboutNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            callPhoneNumber();
                        }
                    });


                    phoneCalls.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            callPhoneNumber();
                        }
                    });


                    aboutCategory.setText(ourSchool.getSchoolType());
                    aboutEmail.setText(ourSchool.getSchoolEmail());

                    aboutEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sendEmail();
                        }
                    });

                    sendEmails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sendEmail();
                        }
                    });
                    aboutWebsite.setText(ourSchool.getSchoolWebsite());
                    aboutWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            setWeblink();
                        }
                    });


                    weblink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            setWeblink();
                        }
                    });
                    LatLng schoollatlng = new LatLng(ourSchool.getLatitude(), ourSchool.getLongitude());
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(schoollatlng).title(ourSchool.getSchoolName()));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(schoollatlng).zoom(15).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                } else if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college") != null) {
                    ourCollege = (OurCollege) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college");
                    collegeAffiliation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    aboutName.setText(ourCollege.getCollegeName());
                    aboutLocation.setText(ourCollege.getCollegeAddress() + "," + ourCollege.getCollegeDistrict() + "," + ourCollege.getCollegeCountry());
                    aboutNumber.setText(ourCollege.getCollegePhone());

                    aboutNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            callPhoneNumber();
                        }
                    });


                    phoneCalls.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            callPhoneNumber();
                        }
                    });
                    aboutCategory.setText(ourCollege.getCollegeType());
                    aboutAffiliation.setText(ourCollege.getCollegeAffiliation());
                    aboutEmail.setText(ourCollege.getCollegeEmail());
                    aboutEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sendEmail();
                        }
                    });

                    sendEmails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sendEmail();
                        }
                    });
                    aboutWebsite.setText(ourCollege.getCollegeWebsite());

                    aboutWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            setWeblink();
                        }
                    });


                    weblink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            setWeblink();
                        }
                    });
                    LatLng collegelatlng = new LatLng(ourCollege.getLatitude(), ourCollege.getLongtitude());
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(collegelatlng).title(ourCollege.getCollegeName()));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(collegelatlng).zoom(15).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                } else {
                    ourUniversity = (OurUniversity) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("university");
                    aboutName.setText(ourUniversity.getUniversityName());
                    aboutLocation.setText(ourUniversity.getUniversityAddress() + "," + ourUniversity.getUniversityDistrict() + "," + ourUniversity.getUniverstiyCountry());
                    aboutNumber.setText(ourUniversity.getUniversityPhone());

                    aboutNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            callPhoneNumber();
                        }
                    });

                    phoneCalls.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            callPhoneNumber();
                        }
                    });
                    aboutCategory.setText(ourUniversity.getUniversityType());
                    aboutEmail.setText(ourUniversity.getUniversityEmail());

                    aboutEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sendEmail();
                        }
                    });


                    sendEmails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sendEmail();
                        }
                    });
                    aboutWebsite.setText(ourUniversity.getUniversityWebsite());

                    aboutWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            setWeblink();
                        }
                    });


                    weblink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            setWeblink();
                        }
                    });
                    LatLng unilatlng = new LatLng(ourUniversity.getUniversityLatitude(), ourUniversity.getUniversityLongitude());
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(unilatlng).title(ourUniversity.getUniversityName()));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(unilatlng).zoom(15).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                }
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    public void callPhoneNumber() {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 101);

                    return;
                }
                OurSchool ourSchool = null;
                OurCollege ourCollege = null;
                OurUniversity ourUniversity = null;
                if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school") != null) {
                    ourSchool = (OurSchool) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school");
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ourSchool.getSchoolPhone()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                } else if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college") != null) {
                    ourCollege = (OurCollege) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college");
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ourCollege.getCollegePhone()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                } else
                    ourUniversity = (OurUniversity) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("university");
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ourUniversity.getUniversityPhone()));
                startActivity(callIntent);


            } else {
                OurSchool ourSchool = null;
                OurCollege ourCollege = null;
                OurUniversity ourUniversity = null;
                if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school") != null) {
                    ourSchool = (OurSchool) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school");
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ourSchool.getSchoolPhone()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                } else if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college") != null) {
                    ourCollege = (OurCollege) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college");
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ourCollege.getCollegePhone()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                } else {
                    ourUniversity = (OurUniversity) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("university");
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ourUniversity.getUniversityPhone()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 101) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                callPhoneNumber();
            } else {
                Log.e("Permission not Granted", "");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    public void sendEmail() {
        OurSchool ourSchool = null;
        OurCollege ourCollege = null;
        OurUniversity ourUniversity = null;
        if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school") != null) {
            ourSchool = (OurSchool) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school");
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", ourSchool.getSchoolEmail(), null));
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
        } else if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college") != null) {
            ourCollege = (OurCollege) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college");
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", ourCollege.getCollegeEmail(), null));
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
        } else {
            ourUniversity = (OurUniversity) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("university");
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", ourUniversity.getUniversityEmail(), null));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
        }
        try {

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void setWeblink() {

        OurSchool ourSchool = null;
        OurCollege ourCollege = null;
        OurUniversity ourUniversity = null;
        if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school") != null) {
            ourSchool = (OurSchool) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://" + ourSchool.getSchoolWebsite()));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college") != null) {
            ourCollege = (OurCollege) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("college");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://" + ourCollege.getCollegeWebsite()));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            ourUniversity = (OurUniversity) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("university");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://" + ourUniversity.getUniversityWebsite()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        try {

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }




}
```

> when i back through the any other fragment .The app closes but i want
>   to display the default fragment.can this be done???

Comment: Hey @Ghimire refer this example you will get your solution https://github.com/colaboy2004/FragmentTabHostExample

Comment: Do i have to use backstack? @piyushpatel

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Yes for go to previous fragment you need to use backstack

Comment: @piyush check the edited code.All are working good but the title is not changing when backed to default fragment

Comment: @Ghimire check I have pasted sample code for replace and backpress put in your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check fragment instance in onBackPress event

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.flContent);

    if(!(fragment instanceof YourDefaultFragment)){
          //Load your default fragment

          toolBarLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          toolBarTitle.setText("Set Title");
    }
    else{
         super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: i got one problem. The back is working but the title is not changing mate.#edited code please check

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using interface, backstack listner and onBackPress following way

Create BaseFragment

public class FlipkartBaseFragment extends Fragment {

```
private MainFlipkartActivity activity;

private ChangeCurrentFragment changeCurrentFragment;



@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = (MainFlipkartActivity) getActivity();

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof ChangeCurrentFragment)
    changeCurrentFragment = (ChangeCurrentFragment) context;

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    changeCurrentFragment=null;

}

public ChangeCurrentFragment onChangeCurrentFragment(){

    return changeCurrentFragment;

}

public MainFlipkartActivity getBaseActivity() {

    return activity;

}
```

}

Then extend all fragment using BaseFragment
In fragment you can go one fragment to other like 
  ((MainFlipkartActivity) getBaseActivity()).onFragmentChangeListener(new TwoFKTFragment(),"1"+new Random().nextInt());

Then implement MainActivity like this way

```
public class MainFlipkartActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener,ChangeCurrentFragment 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            HomeFragment cameraImportFragment = new HomeFragment();
            manageFragment(cameraImportFragment, Const.TAG_HOME);
        }
      }

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            finish();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }

}

   public void manageFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        //    String f_name=fragment.getClass().getName();
        if(!fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tag,0))
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);
            ft.commit();

        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onFragmentChangeListener(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        manageFragment(fragment,tag);
    }




    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fr = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
        if(fr!=null){
            fr.onResume();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Replace fragment if you want back to previous fragment pass addToBackStack=true

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (addToBackStack) {
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }



public boolean popFragment() {
        Log.e("test", "pop fragment: " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        boolean isPop = false;
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            isPop = true;
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        return isPop;
}
```

put this code in your main activity for backpress

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!popFragment()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: replaceFragment(Search,true); search is not recognized in this.

below code is working but title is not changing
  /*  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.flContent);

        if (!(fragment instanceof Search)) {
            FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.flContent, new Search());
            tx.commit();

        }
     }   */

Comment: first time you need to pass false for second fragment you will go for true